# Change variable within array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

My target is to assign a number to the string in the array.

```
  $lang = array (
    'title'         => "Der Anti-Spam Dienst",
    'button-login'  => "Jetzt $number via Twitter anmelden."
   );
```

The $number should be set like $lang['button-login'][5] - but I don't have any idea how to access the variable in the array.
maybe you can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare the `$number` variable before the array:

```
$number = 5;

$lang = array(
    'title'         => "Der Anti-Spam Dienst",
    'button-login'  => "Jetzt $number via Twitter anmelden."
);
```

---

**Update**: If you want to set it afterwards, you'll have to use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$lang = array(
    'title'         => 'Der Anti-Spam Dienst',
    'button-login'  => 'Jetzt $number via Twitter anmelden.'
);

echo str_replace('$number', 5, $lang['button-login']);
```

See it here in action: http://viper-7.com/7QtpF7

**Note:** the strings should be surrounded by single quotes, so that `$number` is not parsed as a variable.

Comment: Thats the point, I want to set the $number variable while i want to get the string for button-login. Do you think its possible? (Thanks so far)

Comment: @H3rrVorr4g3nd - Not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do. If you want to do it afterwards, see my update.